# setting up a basic elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

Im new to elasticsearch and would like someone to help me clarify a few concepts

Im designing a small cluster with the following requirements

- everything should still work when restarting one of the machines, one at a time (eg: OS updates)
- a single disk failure is ok
- heavy indexing should not impact query performance

How many master, data, ingest nodes should I have?
or do I need 2 clusters?

the indexing workload is purely indexing structured text documents, no processing/rules... do I even need an ingest node?

Also, does each node have a complete copy of the all the data? or only a cluster has the complete copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Be sure to read the documentation about [Elasticsearch terminology](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/glossary.html) at the very least.
2. With the default of 1 replica (primary shard and one replica shard) you can survive the failure of 1 Elasticsearch node (failed disk, restart, upgrade,...).
3. "heavy indexing should not impact query performance": You'll need to size your cluster correctly to handle both the indexing and searching. If you want to read current data and you do heavy updates, that will take up resources and you won't be able to fully decouple it.
4. By default every node is a data, ingest, and master-eligible node. The minimum HA setting needs 3 nodes. If you don't use ingest that's fine; it won't take up resources when you're not using it.
5. To understand which node has which data, you need to read up on the concept of shards. Basically every index is broken up into 1 to N shards (current default is 5) and there is one primary and one replica copy of each one of them (by default).

Comment: I have read the documentation and articles on the web but still have some questions. to achieve what i described with the minimum machines, my previous understanding was that I needed 2 nodes in the same cluster each with (primary and replica shard. the data would be split 50% in each node?). However, I read somewhere that this would create a split brain situation and data may become corrupted when one of the nodes is down. With 3 nodes, each node only gets 33%? do I need to specify where each index resides and is it handled automatically?

Comment: Yes, for the master election you will need 3 master-eligible nodes, so that you can avoid the split brain situation (by setting the minimum master nodes to the majority of eligible nodes, which is 2 out of 3). So the smallest cluster that is highly available needs to have 3 nodes. By default the shards will be evenly distributed over all your nodes. While you can influence this it probably doesn't make sense for such a small setup and there is a high chance that you'll make it worse than better than the default shard allocation.

Comment: so 1 cluster with 3 nodes on default settings (5 primary shards and 5 replica shards), should allow me to restart one node at a time without any data loss and everything will keep working?

Comment: or should I change them to 3 primary and 3 replica shards for a 3 node cluster?

Comment: The number of primary shards won't really influence the resiliency. Generally don't overshard, since that is costly in resources. If you have a few indices you could use 1 primary shard and a replication factor of 1 (so 1 primary shard and one replica shard). That will then survive the failure of 1 node. If you don't have too much data and want more resiliency or search performance you could also use 1 primary shard and a replication factor of 2; then every node would hold a complete copy.

Comment: thanks for the answer. for a 3 node cluster, would it be ok if one of the nodes had less system memory than the other 2? or they need to have the same amount of ram?

Comment: is 1 slower node going to slow everything down?

Comment: one last question: is it correct that a search or index request has to be sent to the master node? 
  it seems any of the 3 nodes could become a master node, how does the client know which one is the current master node (which IP address)?
  or do you provide all 3 IPs and the client will try each?

  thanks again. this has been very helpful

Comment: The master only maintains the cluster state (which nodes are there, which indices, where are the shards of an index, mappings,...). Every index operation first goes to the primary shard and then to every replica shard. How do you know which one is the primary shard? Every query has a coordinating node (round robin between all the nodes) and that one forwards the request to the primary shard which in turn forwards it to the replica shards.

Comment: For more advanced setups you could have a multi tier architecture (hot / warm), but for your scenario one slower node will generally impact the overall performance. To keep it simple for starters I would use 3 equal nodes.

Comment: when making a request to node 1's IP and if the primary shard for the index is in in node 3 the request gets routed to node 3 automatically by node 1? is that right? the user doesn't need to know where that primary shard resides

Comment: First, even if you just have just one IP configured, it will automatically sniff the other IPs and will then round robin between them. Second, the node you connect to will automatically forward your request to the right shards (these might be multiple ones on different nodes).